# Why doesn't <rich:datascroller> work in a <h:form>?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a jsf page in the form of

```
<h:form>
  <rich:dataTable id="myTable">
    <!--Table Data-->
  </rich:dataTable>
  <rich:dataScroller for="myTable"/>
</h:form>
```

When the table is in a `<h:form>` it doesn't scroll (the scroller is disabled) but once I take them out of the `<h:form>` it works fine. Issue is I need them to be in a form for the rest of my code to work. Anyone know the reason for the issue? I've seen people ask about it but no good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using the form in a modal pane and the `<ui:include>` was within a `<h:form>` so there was an issue with it being a form within a form.